# Error while Adding JSON data to the list in flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter, dart, flutter-listview

Below is the JSON data retrieved successfully from the server in flutter application

```
{
    "error": "false",
    "notification": [
        {
            "rn": "1",
            "id": "224",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "2",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "2",
            "id": "219",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "3",
            "id": "213",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "4",
            "id": "209",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "4",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "5",
            "id": "204",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "6",
            "id": "199",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        },
        {
            "rn": "7",
            "id": "193",
            "company_details": {
                "code": "3",
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

The code used here is below

```
List notificationsList;
getnotifications(int page) async {

    Map data = {
      'user_id': “VICKY,
      "page":page.toString()
    };


    var response = await http.post(companyorders, body: data);
    if(response.statusCode == 200) {

      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');


      String errorcheck = jsonResponse['error'];




      companyDetail = NotificationModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

      companyDetail = NotificationModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

      print('names of companies');
      print(companyDetail.content);

      List list = jsonResponse['notification'];

      notificationsList.add(list);
     
    }
    
  }
```

When I tried to add the `list` to the `notificationsList` I got the below error

> Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on
> null. Receiver: null Tried calling: add(Instance(length:7) of
> '_GrowableList')
> #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)

I want to add the data retrieved to the `notificationsList`, how should I do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `notificationsList`:

```
List notificationsList = [];
```

Also since `list` is an iterable  therefore use [`addAll()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/addAll.html)